# onChange Trigger not firing when using Google Drive API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a backend Ruby app that updates files in Google Drive using their API. On those files I have Google App Scripts running. I am having an issue when I update a file in google drive using my backend ruby script the Google App Script onChange or onEdit triggers don't fire. They only fire if I go into the file through the browser and edit something myself. Does anyone know why this is? Or a work around for it?

Thanks!

Comment: Sheets API version 3 or newer will trigger the On Change event.  You can use the Sheets REST API from within Apps Script to trigger the On Change event.  Use `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)` to use the Sheet REST API within Apps Script.

Answer (score 4):

The Apps Script onChange and onEdit triggers don't respond to changes made by the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) or the older [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/). They only respond to changes made by a user in the browser UI.

Comment: Well that stinks. Is there any workaround for this? Or some kinda of hacky way to do it?

Comment: You can have an Apps Script run a regular time-based trigger to check for changes in the spreadsheet, and react when changes are detected.

Comment: Ya looks like that may be the best way. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: **Do note that `onChange`  works for changes made by some APIs.**