# doPost(e) does not trigger onChange(e) - Trigger On Change event in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, onchange

I have a very simple doPost(e) script project which is working as a webhook endpoint. It simply records the received JSON payload to A2 cell of a target spreadsheet. In the target spreadsheet, I have an onChange(e) trigger which is passing this payload to an external API. Though there is no error during runtime, my onChange(e) script is not triggered at all. Provided I cut/paste the cell content on the sheet, onChange(e) is then triggered correctly.

In Google Developers page [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/), some restrictions are mentioned but it's also said to be that those restrictions does not apply to doGet(e) and doPost(e).

What am I missing?

Here is my doPost code:

```
var SHEETID = "my_sheetID_here";

function doPost(e) {
  try {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    var sSht = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEETID);
    var sht = sSht.getSheetByName("TEMP");
    sht.getRange("A2").setValue(e.postData.contents);

    return ContentService    // return json success results
    .createTextOutput(
      JSON.stringify({"result":"success",
                  "data": JSON.stringify(data) }))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch (e) {
    MailApp.sendEmail("xx@xx.com,yy@xx.com", "FireStation Webhook Error Occured!", 
      "\r\nMessage: " + e.message
      + "\r\nFile: " + e.fileName
      + "\r\nLine: " + e.lineNumber);
    e = (typeof e === 'string') ? new Error(e) : e;
    Logger.severe('%s: %s (line %s, file "%s"). Stack: "%s" . While processing %s.',e.name||'', 
           e.message||'', e.lineNumber||'', e.fileName||'', e.stack||'', processingMessage||'');
    throw e;
  }
}
```

And here is my onChange(e) code in the target sheet:

```
function onChange(e) {
  try {
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var sheetname = sheet.getName();
    Logger.log("Sheetname: "+sheetname);
    if (sheetname === "TEMP" && sheet.getRange("A2").getValue() !== "") {
      var payload = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
      var URL = "my_external_api_URL_here";
      var options =
      {
        "method"  : "POST",
        "payload" : payload,   
        "followRedirects" : true,
        "muteHttpExceptions": true
      };
      var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, options);
      Logger.log("HTTP Response: "+result.getResponseCode())
    }
  } catch (e) {
    MailApp.sendEmail("xx@xx.com,yy@xx.com", "FireStation Template GAS Error Occured!", 
      "\r\nMessage: " + e.message
      + "\r\nFile: " + e.fileName
      + "\r\nLine: " + e.lineNumber);
    e = (typeof e === 'string') ? new Error(e) : e;
    Logger.severe('%s: %s (line %s, file "%s"). Stack: "%s" . While processing %s.',e.name||'', 
           e.message||'', e.lineNumber||'', e.fileName||'', e.stack||'', processingMessage||'');
    throw e;
  }
}
```

Comment: Apps Script triggers are triggered by "user on-keyboard" actions by time (time-driven) only

Comment: As you mention, some restrictions do not apply to `doGet` and `doPost`. Note also that `onChange` is neither of those two. What you can infer is that the Apps Script *session* started by an invocation of `doGet/Post` will be able to run longer than 30 seconds, etc. (still subject to whatever user permissions you scope with). If you need to activate `onChange` from your webapp code, then just call it explicitly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onChange Trigger not firing when using Google Drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639180/onchange-trigger-not-firing-when-using-google-drive-api)

Comment: As @Sandy Good stated earlier than me, instead of using built-in Sheets service i.e. *SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetid)* and *Range.setValue()*, using **Sheets API version 4** solves the problem and triggers the onChange(e) on the target spreadsheet. Note that this solution requires **Advanced Google Services/Sheet API** to be enabled from the Developer Console.

Comment: You should post an answer with your solution.  It's different than my solution, so it's a valid answer.  And it may be a preferred answer, even though you marked my answer as correct.  And you may get an up-vote on your answer, which will give you points.  It's not often that people answer their own questions, but in this case it's justified.

Comment: @Sandy Good thanks for your kind advice. I had edited my post and record the solution there, but upon your advice, I have posted it as an answer to my question. Thnx for the heads-up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sheets API can be used to trigger the "On Change" event.  Don't use `setValues(array)`.  Remove that code and add a function to write the value to the spreadsheet.

You may need to set the scopes in the appsscript.json file (manifest file).

### Manifest (appsscript.json) file

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "MYSELF",
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING"
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"]
}
```

If there are other scopes that you are using, find them in the "File" "Project Properties" and Scopes tab.  Copy them out and put them in the appsscript.json file in order to maintain the same scopes.

### Your code modified:

```
function doPost(e) {
  try {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

    writeToSheet({shName:"TEMP",ssFileID:SHEETID,data:data});//Write data to sheet using API

    return ContentService    // return json success results
    .createTextOutput(
      JSON.stringify({"result":"success",
                  "data": JSON.stringify(data) }))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch (e) {

    //code . . . .
}
```

### New function:

Function that uses the Sheets API v4 with `valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED` option:

```
function writeToSheet(po) {
  var id,options,range,response,sh,targetSheetName,ss,url,values;

  targetSheetName = po.shName;
  id = po.ssFileID;

  range = targetSheetName + "!A2:A2";

  values = {values: [[po.data]]}; 

  url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" +
    id + "/values/" + range + ":append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED";

  options = {
    "method":"post",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    },
    "contentType": "application/json", 
    "payload": JSON.stringify(values) 
  }

  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)
  response = JSON.parse(response);

  Logger.log('response ' + JSON.stringify(response))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sandy...I have discovered that out also and updated my query as such! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

## SOLUTION

Instead of using built-in Sheets services i.e. *SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetid)* and *Range.setValue()*, using [Sheets API version 4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/) solves the problem and triggers the onChange(e) on the target spreadsheet. Note that this solution requires [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)/Sheet API to be enabled from the Developer Console.

Here is the latest version of my doPost(e) call and it's working beautifully:

```
var SHEETID = "my_sheet_id_here";

function doPost(e) {
  try {
    var data = e.postData.contents;
    var rowValues = [
      [data,""],
    ];

    var request = {
      'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED',
      'data': [
        {
          "range": "TEMP!A2:B2",
          "majorDimension": "ROWS",
          "values": rowValues,
        },
      ],
    };

    var response = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(request, SHEETID);

    return ContentService    // return json success results
    .createTextOutput(
      JSON.stringify({"result":"success",
                  "data": JSON.stringify(data) }))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch (e) {
    MailApp.sendEmail("levent@able3ventures.com,alkio@able3ventures.com", "FireStation Webhook Error Occured!", 
      "\r\nMessage: " + e.message
      + "\r\nFile: " + e.fileName
      + "\r\nLine: " + e.lineNumber);
      e = (typeof e === 'string') ? new Error(e) : e;
      Logger.severe('%s: %s (line %s, file "%s"). Stack: "%s" . While processing %s.',e.name||'', 
           e.message||'', e.lineNumber||'', e.fileName||'', e.stack||'', processingMessage||'');
      throw e;
  }
}
```